# Rails view conditionals if/elsif on user fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to show a table of user data on my site - so I'm using a loop that iterates over the users and displays their info. Before, it was really simple, but I wanted to add conditionals that handled cases where they might not have a city, state, or either entered. When I only have one case entered, it works fine. When I have both, it works fine. User location is defined in the model as a JOIN of city and state. So don't worry there. But when I have neither, it doesn't display the '---' that I want. What am I missing here?

```
<tr>
  <% @user.each do |user| %>
    <td><%= link_to user.username, public_profile_path(user.username) %><br/></td>

    <% if user.state != nil and user.city != nil %>
      <td><%= user.location %></td>
    <% elsif user.state != nil and user.city == nil %>
      <td><%= user.state %></td>
    <% elsif user.state == nil and user.city != nil %>
      <td><%= user.city %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td>---</td>
    <% end %>

    <% if user.phone != nil %>
      <td><%= user.phone %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td>-</td>
    <% end %>

    <td><%= mail_to user.email.to_s, "Email this User", :cc => "michaelomchenry@gmail.com",
        :subject => "Contact from Overflow Member" %></td> 

  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you share what does get output to the source of the page? Is it just nothing, or is there a different unexpected behavior?

Comment: No it outputs to the view if one or the other have values (city or state), and if it has both, it joins them using something I shoved in the model, but if neither have them it won't output anything, even if I ask it to, as shown above.

def location
    [city.to_s.camelcase, state.to_s.upcase].reject(&:blank?).join(", ")
  end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd add a helper method, called location_display or something along those lines that handled all the logic around what should be displayed.

```
def location_display(user)
  return user.location if user.state && user.city
  return user.state if user.state && user.city.blank?
  return user.city if user.city && user.state.blank?
  "----"
end
```

Then, in your view, just replace all those lines with:

```
  <td><%= location_display(user) %></td>
```

Comment: I'm currently using this in the item model to control that. Would this replace it?

    def location
        [city.to_s.camelcase, state.to_s.upcase].reject(&:blank?).join(", ")
    end

Comment: This idea's really great, though. I'm going to give it a shot. The code that I posted felt really klunky. I hate big conditionals like that. And I would assume putting it in a view is less than ideal.

Comment: Yeah, you could just move that location logic straight into that helper directly if you aren't using it anywhere else.  It's really more of a view concern than a model concern, so it makes more sense to be in a helper.  I avoid having if logic in my views whenever possible, helpers tend to be my goto for working around things like this